# paging toolbar events in ExtJS4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

We are moving to ExtJS4.But we are facing an issue with paging toolbar events(onClick and onPagingKeyDown).These two are working with ExtJS3.But now these are not working.

ExtJS3 code is:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({      
store : examplestore,
columns : [{
header : s.no,
width : 40
},{
header : company name,
width : 100
},{
header : address,
width : 150
}],
bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
pageSize : 10,
store : examplestore,
width : 350,
onClick : function(){
alert('you have clicked');
},
onPagingKeyDown : function(){
alert('hello');
}
})
});
```

ExtJS4 code is:

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.GridPanel',{      
    store : examplestore,
    columns : [{
    header : s.no,
    width : 40
    },{
    header : company name,
    width : 100
    },{
    header : address,
    width : 150
    }],
    bbar: Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Paging',{
    pageSize : 10,
    store : examplestore,
    width : 350,
    onClick : function(){
    alert('you have clicked');
    },
    onPagingKeyDown : function(){
    alert('hello');
    }
    })
    });
```

Now we are facing an issue with these onClick and onPagingKeyDown events that are not in ExtJS4.How to achieve these two events?

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onPagingKeyDown` is in ExtJS4. But it is private and it's not recommended to use it. Instead of both `onClick` and `onPagingKeyDown` you can use [`beforechange`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging-event-beforechange) event.

Comment: Yeah i tried with befirechange event.but i am getting the expected result which i am getting by using onClick and onPagingKeyDown.If you have any example please share with us.

Comment: yeah thanks for our reply molecule.We got the solution.We have used change listener instead of beforechange.Now its working fine.Thanks a lot.